# postgres: join against partitioned table

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization, partitioning, postgresql-performance

I want to join against a huge partitioned table. The planner probably assumes that the partitioned table is very cheap to scan.

I have the following query:

```
select * 
from (
        select users where age < 18 limit 10
    ) as users 
    join 
    clicks on users.id = clicks.userid
where
    clicks.ts between '2015-01-01' and now();
```

The table `clicks` is the master table with roughly 40 child tables containing together about 40 million records.

This query performs very slow. When I look at the planner postgres first performs a complete scan of the `clicks` table and then scans the user table.

However when I limit the `users` subquery to 1 the planner first scans the users and then the clicks.

It seems as if the planner assumes that the `clicks` table is very lightweight. If I look at the stats in `pg_class` the master table `clicks` has 0 tuples. Which is true on the one hand because it is a master table, but on the other hand, for the planner it should contain the sum of all its child tables.

How can I force the planner to use the cheapest option first?

---

**edit**: in simplifying the query I indeed missed out an additional  constraint on the date.

The partitioning constraints are on: `clicks.ts` and `clicks.userid`

I have indexes on `users.age`, `user.id`, `clicks.userid` and `clicks.ts`

Maybe I have to trust the planner. I am just a little insecure because I once had a case where postgres showed some weird behavior with limits ([PostgreSQL query very slow with limit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385555/postgresql-query-very-slow-with-limit-1/27237698)).

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE at http://explain.depesz.com ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Here is the result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE: http://explain.depesz.com/s/66bH

Comment: my version `PostgreSQL 9.1.15 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit`

Comment: *`select users where age < 18`* Does this actually run on your machine?

Comment: Could you show us the DDL for these tables, including indexes? Moving the subselect to a common table expression might help, not sure.

Comment: What is your partitioning constraint? Do you have an index for userid on child tables?

Comment: The query in your question and the query that produced that execution plan seem to be two different things. Partitioning presumes most queries will need to hit just a few partitions; your query has to hit all of them.