# PostgreSQL slow query with limit 1 and order by unneeded where condition

Tags: postgresql, performance, limit

I have one table `accounts` and indexes

```sql
accounts {
    id  text
    num_id  bigint
    pid text
    fid text
    created_at  timestamp with time zone
    updated_at  timestamp with time zone
}

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX accounts_pkey ON public.accounts USING btree (id)
CREATE INDEX fid_idx ON public.accounts USING btree (fid)
CREATE INDEX idx_accounts_pid_fid ON public.accounts USING btree (pid, fid)
```

And this query is slow

```sql
explain analyse SELECT * FROM accounts
WHERE pid = 'hd' AND fid = '123'
ORDER BY  id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..3173.34 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=49389.351..49389.351 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using accounts_pkey on accounts  (cost=0.56..5022497.13 rows=1583 width=123) (actual time=49389.350..49389.350 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((pid = 'hd'::text) AND (fid = '123'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 56821193
Planning time: 0.094 ms
Execution time: 49389.368 ms
```

Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27237698/3011380), it may be solved by adding unneeded where condition `pid` and `fid`

```sql
explain analyse SELECT * FROM accounts
WHERE pid = 'hd' AND fid = '123'
ORDER BY  id ASC, pid, fid
LIMIT 1;
```

However, it does not work

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..3173.37 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=49495.236..49495.236 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using accounts_pkey on accounts  (cost=0.56..5022556.07 rows=1583 width=123) (actual time=49495.234..49495.234 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: ((pid = 'hd'::text) AND (fid = '123'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 56821555
Planning time: 0.096 ms
Execution time: 49495.253 ms
```

Is there I am missing?

PostgreSQL version: 9.6.8

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the running time of `SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY id LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the running time of `SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` is `Limit  (cost=0.56..0.65 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using accounts_pkey on accounts  (cost=0.56..4738719.60 rows=56980788 width=123) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.078 ms
Execution time: 0.027 ms
`

Comment: I attempted an answer below which hopefully partially explains what you are seeing.  I don't know why Postgres is choosing this execution plan, but a slight change in index definition might get around all of the problems.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, the following query is in fact quite performant:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

The reason this performs well is that the `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` step is the only thing which Postgres needs to do before `SELECT`, and the `accounts_pkey` unique index can easily be scanned here.  Actually, Postgres only needs to find the lowest `id` value, and then refer back to the clustered index to cover the `SELECT *`.

However, the query in your question is a bit different:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE pid = 'hd' AND fid = '123'
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

In this case, Postgres is choosing to scan the entire `accounts_pkey` index, starting with a filter step corresponding to your `WHERE` clause.  Because `accounts_pkey` only covers the `id` column, Postgres must seek back to the clustered index to lookup the value of `pid` and `fid`.  Ideally, Postgres would just start with the lowest `id` value and walk down the index until finding the first match on the `pid` and `fid` values.  Regardless of what Postgres is deciding to do, the following covering index could help here:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_accounts_cover ON public.accounts USING btree (pid, fid, id);
```

Given that nearly 6 million records could now easily be removed using the above index, the remaining `LIMIT`/`ORDER BY` operation on `id` might be more tolerable.  And since this index also covers `id`, Postgres only would have to a seek back to clustered index once, at the very end of the query.

Comment: Possibly extremely low cardinality on the `pid, fid` index? (just because this one case has reasonable cardinality doesn't exclude the other combinations having very low cardinality...)

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, I was also thinking this, and wanted to see a sample of the OP's data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I did get a chance to add this index `(pid, fid, id)` in production env. However, I test it in beta env. After adding this index, the explain result is `)->  Sort  (cost=8.39..8.39 rows=1 width=119) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)Sort Key: id  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
->  Index Scan using fid_idx on accounts  (cost=0.29..8.38 rows=1 width=119) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=0 loops=1) Index Cond: (fid = '123'::text) Filter: (pid = 'hd'::text)`. `fid_idx` is used rather than  idx_accounts_cover

Comment: @zangw OK...the thing here is that the fastest Postgres could be would be to walk down the index on `id` and stop when finding the first matching record.  But, if very few of your millions of records match `pid` and `fid`, then this process could take some time, regardless of strategy used.