# Postgres SLOWER when a LIMIT is set: how to fix besides adding a dummy `ORDER BY`?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, sql-execution-plan, explain

In Postgres, some queries are a whole lot slower when adding a `LIMIT`:

### The queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY done DESC LIMIT 4; -- 51 sec
SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY id, done DESC LIMIT 4; -- 0.020s
SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 LIMIT 4; -- 0.007s
SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY id; -- 0.007s
```

As you can see, I need to add a dummy id to the `ORDER BY` in order for things to go fast. I'm trying to understand why.

Running `EXPLAIN` on them:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY done DESC LIMIT 4;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY id, done DESC LIMIT 4;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 LIMIT 4;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY id;
```

gives this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY done DESC LIMIT 4
Limit  (cost=0.44..249.76 rows=4 width=56)
  ->  Index Scan using review_done on review  (cost=0.44..913081.13 rows=14649 width=56)
        Filter: (clicker_id = 28)


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY id, done DESC LIMIT 4
Limit  (cost=11970.75..11970.76 rows=4 width=56)
  ->  Sort  (cost=11970.75..12007.37 rows=14649 width=56)
        Sort Key: id, done DESC
        ->  Index Scan using review_clicker_id on review  (cost=0.44..11751.01 rows=14649 width=56)
              Index Cond: (clicker_id = 28)


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 LIMIT 4
Limit  (cost=0.44..3.65 rows=4 width=56)
  ->  Index Scan using review_clicker_id on review  (cost=0.44..11751.01 rows=14649 width=56)
        Index Cond: (clicker_id = 28)


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28 ORDER BY id
Sort  (cost=12764.61..12801.24 rows=14649 width=56)
  Sort Key: id
  ->  Index Scan using review_clicker_id on review  (cost=0.44..11751.01 rows=14649 width=56)
        Index Cond: (clicker_id = 28)
```

I'm no SQL expert, but I take it Postgres expected the query to be faster than it actually is, and so used a way to fetch the data that's actually inappropriate, correct?

### The database:

- The `review` table:

  - Contains 22+ million rows.

    - A given user will get 7 066 rows tops.
    - The one in the test (id 28) has 288 at the time.
  - Has this structure:

    - id: bigint Auto Increment [nextval('public.review_id_seq')]
    - type:   review_type NULL
    - iteration:  smallint NULL
    - repetitions:    smallint NULL
    - due:    timestamptz NULL
    - done:   timestamptz NULL
    - added:  timestamptz NULL
    - clicker_id: bigint NULL
    - monologue_id:   bigint NULL
  - Has these indexes:

    - UNIQUE  type, clicker_id, monologue_id, iteration
    - INDEX   clicker_id
    - INDEX   done, due, monologue_id
    - INDEX   id
    - INDEX   done DESC
    - INDEX   type

### Additional details:

#### Environment:

- The queries were ran in development with Postgres 9.6.14.
- Running the queries into production (Heroku Postgres, version 9.6.16) the difference is less dramatic, but still not great: the slow queries might take 600 ms.

#### Variable speed:

- Sometimes, the same queries (be it the exact same, or for a different clicker_id) run a lot faster (under 1 sec), but I don't understand why. I need them to be *consistently* fast.
- If I use `LIMIT 288` for a user that has 288 rows, then it's so much faster (< 1sec), but if I do the same for a user with say 7066 rows then it's back to super slow.

#### Before I figured the use of a dummy `ORDER BY`, I tried these:

- Re-importing the database.
- `analyze review;`
- Setting the index for done to DESC (used to be set to default/ASC.) [The challenge then was that there's [no proper way to check if/when the index is done rebuilding](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/monitoring-progress-of-index-construction-in-postgresql).]

None helped.

### The question:

My issue in itself is solved, but I'm dissatisfied with it:

- Is there a **name for this "pattern"** that consists of adding a dummy `ORDER BY` to speed things up?
- **How can I spot** such issues in the future? (This took ages to figure.) Unless I missed something, the `EXPLAIN` is not that useful:

  - For the slow query, the cost is misleadingly slow, while for the fast variant it's misleadingly high.
- Alternative: **is there another way to handle this?** (Because this solution feels like a hack.)

Thanks!

---

*Similar questions:*

- [PostgreSQL query very slow with limit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385555/postgresql-query-very-slow-with-limit-1/27237698) is almost the same question, except his queries were slow with LIMIT 1 and fine with LIMIT 3 or higher. And then of course the data is not the same.

Comment: what happens when you run an Analyze on that table and then run the select ?

Comment: @RajVerma Nothing particular, it's still just as slow as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue here is what's called an abort-early query plan. Here's a thread from pgsql-hackers describing something similar:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/541A2335.3060100%40agliodbs.com

Quoting from there, this is why the planner is using the often-extremely-slow index scan when the ORDER BY done DESC is present:

> As usual, PostgreSQL is dramatically undercounting n_distinct: it shows
>   chapters.user_id at 146,000 and the ratio of to_user_id:from_user_id as
>   being 1:105 (as opposed to 1:6, which is about the real ratio).  This
>   means that PostgreSQL thinks it can find the 20 rows within the first 2%
>   of the index ... whereas it actually needs to scan 50% of the index to
>   find them.

In your case, the planner thinks that if it just starts going through rows ordered by done desc (IOW, using the review_done index), it will find 4 rows with clicker_id=28 quickly. Since the rows need to be returned in "done" descending order, it thinks this will save a sort step and be faster than retrieving all rows for clicker 28 and then sorting. Given the real-world distribution of rows, this can often turn out not to be the case, requiring it to skip a huge number of rows before finding 4 with clicker=28.

A more-general way of handling it is to use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/queries-with.html) (which, in 9.6, is still an optimization fence - this changes in PG 12, FYI) to fetch the rows without an order by, then add the ORDER BY in the outer query. Given that fetching all rows for a user, sorting them, and returning however many you need is completely reasonable for your dataset (even the 7k-rows clicker shouldn't be an issue), you can prevent the planner from believing an abort-early plan will be fastest by not having an ORDER BY or a LIMIT in the CTE, giving you a query of something like:

```
WITH clicker_rows as (SELECT * FROM review WHERE clicker_id=28)
select * From clicker_rows ORDER BY done DESC LIMIT 4;
```

This should be reliably fast while still respecting the ORDER BY and the LIMIT you want. I'm not sure if there's a name for this pattern, though.

Comment: Thanks again for this answer (from almost 1 year and 9 months ago!) The `ORDER BY` trick worked in Postgres 9.6, but not in Postgres 13, with queries taking minutes. Using a CTE as in your example (or a subquery) does work nicely.

Comment: CTE method doesn't work for Postgres 14.

Comment: Will come back later to edit the answer for PG 12+, but short version is to use [`AS MATERIALIZED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html#id-1.5.6.12.7) to force the CTE to be evaluated separately.