# Why is limit 0,1 slower than limit 0, 17

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, query-optimization, limit

I'm trying to analyze why the following query is slower with `LIMIT 0,1` than `LIMIT 0,100`

I've added `SQL_NO_CACHE` for testing purposes.

Query:

```
 SELECT 
  SQL_NO_CACHE  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, 
  low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value AS low_stock_amount
FROM 
  wp_posts 
  LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup ON wp_posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS low_stock_amount_meta ON wp_posts.ID = low_stock_amount_meta.post_id 
  AND low_stock_amount_meta.meta_key = '_low_stock_amount' 
WHERE 
  1 = 1 
  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation') 
  AND (
    (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
  ) 
  AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity IS NOT NULL 
  AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_status IN('instock', 'outofstock') 
  AND (
    (
      low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value > '' 
      AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity <= CAST(
        low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value AS SIGNED
      )
    ) 
    OR (
      (
        low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value IS NULL 
        OR low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value <= ''
      ) 
      AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity <= 2
    )
  ) 

ORDER BY 
  wp_posts.ID DESC 
LIMIT 
  0, 1
```

Explains shows the exact same output

```
1   SIMPLE  wp_posts    index   PRIMARY,type_status_date    PRIMARY 8   NULL    27071   Using where
1   SIMPLE  low_stock_amount_meta   ref post_id,meta_key    meta_key    767 const   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  wc_product_meta_lookup  eq_ref  PRIMARY,stock_status,stock_quantity,product_id  PRIMARY 8   woocommerce-admin.wp_posts.ID   1   Using where
```

The average query time is 350ms with `LIMIT 0,1`

The average query time is 7ms with `LIMIT 0,100`

The query performance gets faster starting with `LIMIT 0,17`

I've added another column to the order by clause as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385555/postgresql-query-very-slow-with-limit-1/27237698#27237698), but that triggers `Using filesort` in the explain output

`Order by wp_posts.post_date, wp_posts.ID desc`

```
1   SIMPLE  wp_posts    ALL PRIMARY,type_status_date    NULL    NULL    NULL    27071   Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  low_stock_amount_meta   ref post_id,meta_key    meta_key    767 const   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  wc_product_meta_lookup  eq_ref  PRIMARY,stock_status,stock_quantity,product_id  PRIMARY 8   woocommerce-admin.wp_posts.ID   1   Using where
```

Is there a way to work around it without altering indices and why is this happening?

It's also interesting that the query time improves starting with `LIMIT 0,17`. I'm not sure why 17 is a magic number here.

Update 1: I just tried adding `FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY)` and now `LIMIT 0,100` has same performance as `LIMIT 0,1` smh

Comment: Usually the second time is best.  The _first_ time includes fetching things from disk.

Comment: @RickJames but I have SQL_NO_CACHE and the difference is 350ms vs 7ms and running LIMIT 0,17 is fast even for the first time.

Comment: The buffer pool is also a cache.  On a fresh system, none of posts and postmeta is loaded until after the first query.  So, if the first query test took several seconds, the "average" would be abnormally high, even if the rest were very low.  (And, yes, it was good to avoid the "Query cache".)

Comment: @RickJames I get what you're saying, but it still does not explain the question of why LIMIT 0, 17 is vastly faster than 0,1 even for the first query. I've even tried to reboot the system to make the system cold.

Comment: Please verify again that your execution plans are actually identical, as this should only happen if they are not. Also, you mentioned that you added "force index(primary)" (where exactly?), are the queries then equally fast or equally slow? What happens if you force all 3 indexes shown in your execution plan?

Comment: @Solarflare I've triple confirmed already. When I add the index, they are equally slow.

Comment: @Moon, some questions for you. Does this query come from someplace in WooCommerce, or is it your own (pllugin / snippet) code? How many rows (order of magnitude) in wp_posts, wp_postmeta, and wp_wc_product_meta_lookup?

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you. Yes, it's from WooCommerce. I'm gonna update the original post, but the performance is the same in MySQL 5.7 or MariaDB. Limit 0,1 execution time is at around 150ms, which is the same as Limit 0,17. My local setup with MySQL 5.6 only shows this weird behavior where Limit 0,17+ is vastly faster SMH

Comment: @O.Jones my postmeta has 979392 rows, posts table has 31995, wp_wc_product_meta_lookup has 31995 rows.

Comment: A million rows in postmeta for Woo? Use the plugin. Seriously. It *will* make your store faster. And, with respect don't waste too much effort trying to figure out performance oddities in old versions of megalines-of-code software like MySQL.

Comment: I think that `varchar <= ''`` will _always_ be `false`, even for `NULL` and negative numbers.  `varchar <= 0`` is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_postmeta` has sloppy indexes; this slows down most queries involving it.

O. Jones and I have made a [*WordPress plugin*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed) to improve the indexing of postmeta.  We detect all sorts of stuff like the presence of the Barracuda version of the InnoDB storage engine, and other MySQL arcana, and do the right thing.

The *may* speed up all three averages.  It is likely to change the `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: Thanks, Rick, but I'm not sure what the plugin does. My `wp_postmeta` table already has index for meta_id, post_id, meta_key, and meta_value. It looks like plugins adds the same index to the table, which I already have.

Comment: Single column indexes is _not_ the same as "composite" (multi-column) indexes.

Comment: Rick James // Ah! I see what you're trying to do. Unfortunately, it did not help in my case.

Comment: Did the `EXPLAINs` change?

Comment: Rick James // No, it did not. As you see in my original post, the output of EXPLAIN is pretty good without any warning signs such as `using temporary` or `using filesort`.

Comment: Interesting. And weird. Maybe the plugin needs to put a compound indes or two on that `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` table; it has one row per WooCommerce SKU.

Comment: Moon, would you be willing to run our plugin's indexing operation again and say "yes" to uploading the diagnostic metadata so we can see it? @RickJames and I are committed (volunteers) trying to help site owners resolve these kinds ofproblems.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing this query. I confess I don't understand the performance change from LIMIT 1 to LIMIT 17.  Still, the problem for your store's customers (or managers) is the slowness on LIMIT 1. So let's address that.

The [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385555/postgresql-query-very-slow-with-limit-1/27237698#27237698) was for postgreSQL, not MySQL. postgreSQL has a more sophisticated way of handling ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 than MySQL does. And, the resolution to that problem was the adding of an appropriate compound index for the required lookup.

It looks to me like the purpose of your query is to find the low-stock or out-of-stock WooCommerce product with the largest `wp_posts.ID`

The LEFT JOIN to the  `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` table should be, and is, straightforward: the ON-condition column mentioned is its primary key. This table is, basically, WooCommerce's materialized view of numeric values like stock_quantity stored in `wp_postmeta`. Numeric values in `wp_postmeta` can't be indexed because that table stores them as text strings. Yeah. I know.

The LEFT JOIN between `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` follows the very common ON-condition pattern `ON posts.ID = meta.post_id AND meta.meta_key = 'constant'`. That ON condition is notorious for poor support by WordPress's standard indexes. More or less the entire purpose of Rick and my [Index WP MySQL For Speed plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) is to provide good compound indexes in `wp_postmeta` to work around that problem.

How so? [This is the DDL](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/wordpress/speeding-up-wordpress-database-operations/#data-definition-language) it runs to add the indexes.  The most important lines for this purpose:  ((There's more to it, read the linked article.)

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY (post_id, meta_key, meta_id);
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD KEY meta_key (meta_key, post_id);
```

These two indexes support the ON-condition pattern in the query. I am pretty sure that adding theses keys to postmeta will make your query more predictable and faster in performance.

If the `ORDER BY post.ID DESC` is a very common use case, an index could be added for that.

You could try refactoring the query (if you have control over its source) to defer the retrieval of details from the `wp_posts` table. Like this.

```sql
SELECT wp_posts.*, postid.low_stock_amount
 FROM (
   wp_posts.ID, low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value AS low_stock_amount
FROM 
  wp_posts 
  LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup ON wp_posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS low_stock_amount_meta ON wp_posts.ID = low_stock_amount_meta.post_id 
  AND low_stock_amount_meta.meta_key = '_low_stock_amount' 
WHERE 
  1 = 1 
  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('product', 'product_variation') 
  AND (
    (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
  ) 
  AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity IS NOT NULL 
  AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_status IN('instock', 'outofstock') 
  AND (
    (
      low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value > '' 
      AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity <= CAST(
        low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value AS SIGNED
      )
    ) 
    OR (
      (
        low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value IS NULL 
        OR low_stock_amount_meta.meta_value <= ''
      ) 
      AND wc_product_meta_lookup.stock_quantity <= 2
    )
  ) 

ORDER BY 
  wp_posts.ID DESC 
LIMIT 
  0, 1
) postid
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = postid.ID
```

This refactoring makes your complex query sort only the `wp_posts.ID` value and then retrieves the posts data once it has the appropriate value in hand.  Lots of WordPress core code does something similar: retrieves a list of post ID values in one query, then retrieves the post data in a second query.

And, by the way, MySQL 8 ignores `SQL_NO_CACHE`.