# Slow Postgres query using LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, sql-limit

I'm experiencing an issue similar to [PostgreSQL query very slow with limit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385555/postgresql-query-very-slow-with-limit-1) and [Extremely slow PostgreSQL query with ORDER and LIMIT clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037843/extremely-slow-postgresql-query-with-order-and-limit-clauses) although in my case it doesn't matter if the `LIMIT` is 1, 5 or 500.

Basically, when I run a query generated by Django's ORM without a limit, the query takes half a second but with the limit (added for pagination) it takes 7 seconds.

The query that takes 7 seconds is:

```
SELECT "buildout_itemdescription"."product_code_id",
         MIN("buildout_lineitem"."unit_price") AS "min_price"
FROM "buildout_lineitem"
INNER JOIN "buildout_itemdescription"
    ON ("buildout_lineitem"."item_description_id" = "buildout_itemdescription"."id")
WHERE (("buildout_lineitem"."report_file_id" IN (154, 172, 155, 181, 174, 156, 157, 182, 175, 176, 183, 158, 177, 159, 179, 178, 164, 180, 367, 165, 173, 166, 167, 168, 368, 422, 370, 169, 1335, 1323, 161, 160, 162, 170, 171, 676, 151, 163, 980, 152, 369, 153, 963, 1718, 881, 617, 1759, 1780, 636, 1199, 1243, 947, 1163, 1422, 1009, 1407, 1035, 1241, 1077, 1271, 1111, 1130, 1489, 1507, 1555, 1600, 1619, 1663)
        AND "buildout_lineitem"."unit_price" > 0
        AND NOT ("buildout_itemdescription"."product_code_id" IS NULL)
        AND "buildout_lineitem"."date" >= '2014-04-20'::date
        AND "buildout_lineitem"."date" <= '2019-03-25'::date))
GROUP BY  "buildout_itemdescription"."product_code_id"
ORDER BY  "buildout_itemdescription"."product_code_id" LIMIT 5
```

And the other query is the same without the LIMIT 5.

Postgres is using very different plans for the two queries (HASH JOIN vs NESTED LOOP).

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Limit",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Startup Cost": 0.86,
      "Total Cost": 1362.36,
      "Plan Rows": 5,
      "Plan Width": 36,
      "Actual Startup Time": 7035.543,
      "Actual Total Time": 7063.808,
      "Actual Rows": 5,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "(min(buildout_lineitem.unit_price))"],
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 1995053,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 1158777,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Aggregate",
          "Strategy": "Sorted",
          "Partial Mode": "Simple",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Startup Cost": 0.86,
          "Total Cost": 35365525.74,
          "Plan Rows": 129877,
          "Plan Width": 36,
          "Actual Startup Time": 7035.541,
          "Actual Total Time": 7063.804,
          "Actual Rows": 5,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "min(buildout_lineitem.unit_price)"],
          "Group Key": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id"],
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 1995053,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 1158777,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Join Type": "Inner",
              "Startup Cost": 0.86,
              "Total Cost": 35362951.28,
              "Plan Rows": 255139,
              "Plan Width": 10,
              "Actual Startup Time": 7035.220,
              "Actual Total Time": 7062.420,
              "Actual Rows": 10660,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "buildout_lineitem.unit_price"],
              "Inner Unique": false,
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 1995053,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 1158777,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                  "Index Name": "buildout_itemdescription_product_code_id_084c51de",
                  "Relation Name": "buildout_itemdescription",
                  "Schema": "public",
                  "Alias": "buildout_itemdescription",
                  "Startup Cost": 0.43,
                  "Total Cost": 143970.67,
                  "Plan Rows": 1003733,
                  "Plan Width": 8,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.074,
                  "Actual Total Time": 627.419,
                  "Actual Rows": 351127,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.id", "buildout_itemdescription.deleted", "buildout_itemdescription.created_on", "buildout_itemdescription.modified_on", "buildout_itemdescription.description", "buildout_itemdescription.category_1", "buildout_itemdescription.category_2", "buildout_itemdescription.category_3", "buildout_itemdescription.manufacturer_sku", "buildout_itemdescription.manufacturer_name", "buildout_itemdescription.distributor_sku", "buildout_itemdescription.supplier_id", "buildout_itemdescription.unit_of_measure", "buildout_itemdescription.quantity_in_unit_of_measure", "buildout_itemdescription.created_by_id", "buildout_itemdescription.modified_by_id", "buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "buildout_itemdescription.region_id"],
                  "Index Cond": "(buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id IS NOT NULL)",
                  "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 195375,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 144994,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0
                },
                {
                  "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                  "Index Name": "buildout_lineitem_item_description_id_88254e09",
                  "Relation Name": "buildout_lineitem",
                  "Schema": "public",
                  "Alias": "buildout_lineitem",
                  "Startup Cost": 0.43,
                  "Total Cost": 35.00,
                  "Plan Rows": 9,
                  "Plan Width": 10,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.018,
                  "Actual Total Time": 0.018,
                  "Actual Rows": 0,
                  "Actual Loops": 351127,
                  "Output": ["buildout_lineitem.id", "buildout_lineitem.deleted", "buildout_lineitem.created_on", "buildout_lineitem.modified_on", "buildout_lineitem.date", "buildout_lineitem.month", "buildout_lineitem.quantity", "buildout_lineitem.unit_price", "buildout_lineitem.extended_sell", "buildout_lineitem.list_price", "buildout_lineitem.list_price_ext", "buildout_lineitem.agreed_price", "buildout_lineitem.agreed_price_ext", "buildout_lineitem.baseline_price", "buildout_lineitem.baseline_price_ext", "buildout_lineitem.item_class", "buildout_lineitem.user_created_by", "buildout_lineitem.sub_region", "buildout_lineitem.business_unit", "buildout_lineitem.created_by_id", "buildout_lineitem.item_description_id", "buildout_lineitem.modified_by_id", "buildout_lineitem.report_file_id"],
                  "Index Cond": "(buildout_lineitem.item_description_id = buildout_itemdescription.id)",
                  "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                  "Filter": "((buildout_lineitem.unit_price > '0'::numeric) AND (buildout_lineitem.date >= '2014-04-20'::date) AND (buildout_lineitem.date <= '2019-03-25'::date) AND (buildout_lineitem.report_file_id = ANY ('{154,172,155,181,174,156,157,182,175,176,183,158,177,159,179,178,164,180,367,165,173,166,167,168,368,422,370,169,1335,1323,161,160,162,170,171,676,151,163,980,152,369,153,963,1718,881,617,1759,1780,636,1199,1243,947,1163,1422,1009,1407,1035,1241,1077,1271,1111,1130,1489,1507,1555,1600,1619,1663}'::integer[])))",
                  "Rows Removed by Filter": 10,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 1799678,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 1013783,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Planning Time": 2.796,
    "Triggers": [
    ],
    "Execution Time": 7063.932
  }
]
```

vs

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Aggregate",
      "Strategy": "Sorted",
      "Partial Mode": "Simple",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Startup Cost": 246569.04,
      "Total Cost": 249781.35,
      "Plan Rows": 129877,
      "Plan Width": 36,
      "Actual Startup Time": 561.755,
      "Actual Total Time": 580.878,
      "Actual Rows": 3771,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "min(buildout_lineitem.unit_price)"],
      "Group Key": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id"],
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 5544,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 27043,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 3729,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 3730,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Sort",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Startup Cost": 246569.04,
          "Total Cost": 247206.89,
          "Plan Rows": 255139,
          "Plan Width": 10,
          "Actual Startup Time": 561.741,
          "Actual Total Time": 568.372,
          "Actual Rows": 79253,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "buildout_lineitem.unit_price"],
          "Sort Key": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id"],
          "Sort Method": "external merge",
          "Sort Space Used": 1624,
          "Sort Space Type": "Disk",
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 5544,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 27043,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 3729,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 3730,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Hash Join",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Join Type": "Inner",
              "Startup Cost": 59518.27,
              "Total Cost": 219295.38,
              "Plan Rows": 255139,
              "Plan Width": 10,
              "Actual Startup Time": 429.997,
              "Actual Total Time": 546.546,
              "Actual Rows": 79253,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "buildout_lineitem.unit_price"],
              "Inner Unique": true,
              "Hash Cond": "(buildout_lineitem.item_description_id = buildout_itemdescription.id)",
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 5541,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 27043,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 3526,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 3526,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                  "Index Name": "buildout_lineitem_report_file_id_b56906e1",
                  "Relation Name": "buildout_lineitem",
                  "Schema": "public",
                  "Alias": "buildout_lineitem",
                  "Startup Cost": 0.43,
                  "Total Cost": 151740.64,
                  "Plan Rows": 332154,
                  "Plan Width": 10,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.063,
                  "Actual Total Time": 30.922,
                  "Actual Rows": 79253,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Output": ["buildout_lineitem.unit_price", "buildout_lineitem.item_description_id"],
                  "Index Cond": "(buildout_lineitem.report_file_id = ANY ('{154,172,155,181,174,156,157,182,175,176,183,158,177,159,179,178,164,180,367,165,173,166,167,168,368,422,370,169,1335,1323,161,160,162,170,171,676,151,163,980,152,369,153,963,1718,881,617,1759,1780,636,1199,1243,947,1163,1422,1009,1407,1035,1241,1077,1271,1111,1130,1489,1507,1555,1600,1619,1663}'::integer[]))",
                  "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                  "Filter": "((buildout_lineitem.unit_price > '0'::numeric) AND (buildout_lineitem.date >= '2014-04-20'::date) AND (buildout_lineitem.date <= '2019-03-25'::date))",
                  "Rows Removed by Filter": 6,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 1610,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 991,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0
                },
                {
                  "Node Type": "Hash",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Startup Cost": 43050.17,
                  "Total Cost": 43050.17,
                  "Plan Rows": 1003733,
                  "Plan Width": 8,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 429.373,
                  "Actual Total Time": 429.373,
                  "Actual Rows": 1005163,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "buildout_itemdescription.id"],
                  "Hash Buckets": 131072,
                  "Original Hash Buckets": 131072,
                  "Hash Batches": 16,
                  "Original Hash Batches": 16,
                  "Peak Memory Usage": 3495,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 3931,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 26052,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 3213,
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Relation Name": "buildout_itemdescription",
                      "Schema": "public",
                      "Alias": "buildout_itemdescription",
                      "Startup Cost": 0.00,
                      "Total Cost": 43050.17,
                      "Plan Rows": 1003733,
                      "Plan Width": 8,
                      "Actual Startup Time": 0.021,
                      "Actual Total Time": 287.632,
                      "Actual Rows": 1005163,
                      "Actual Loops": 1,
                      "Output": ["buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id", "buildout_itemdescription.id"],
                      "Filter": "(buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id IS NOT NULL)",
                      "Rows Removed by Filter": 301554,
                      "Shared Hit Blocks": 3931,
                      "Shared Read Blocks": 26052,
                      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Written Blocks": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Planning Time": 2.965,
    "Triggers": [
    ],
    "Execution Time": 581.324
  }
]
```

In Django, my code is:

```
        from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination


        line_items = LineItem.objects.filter(
            report_file__report=report,
            unit_price__gt=0
        ).exclude(
            item_description__product_code__isnull=True
        )
```

```
        item_refs_aggregated = line_items.values(
            'item_description__product_code_id'
        ).annotate(
            min_price=Min('unit_price'),
        ).values(
            "item_description__product_code",
            "min_price",
        ).order_by(*ordering)


        paginator = LimitOffsetPagination()
        paginator.page_size = 10
        result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(
            item_refs_aggregated,
            request
        )
```

The indexes on these tables are:
**buildout_lineitem:**

```
Indexes:
    "buildout_lineitem_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "buildout_lineitem_created_by_id_a61c52b7" btree (created_by_id)
    "buildout_lineitem_item_description_id_88254e09" btree (item_description_id)
    "buildout_lineitem_modified_by_id_8668530a" btree (modified_by_id)
    "buildout_lineitem_report_file_id_b56906e1" btree (report_file_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "buildout_lineitem_created_by_id_a61c52b7_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (created_by_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "buildout_lineitem_item_description_id_88254e09_fk_buildout_" FOREIGN KEY (item_description_id) REFERENCES buildout_itemdescription(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "buildout_lineitem_modified_by_id_8668530a_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (modified_by_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "buildout_lineitem_report_file_id_b56906e1_fk_buildout_" FOREIGN KEY (report_file_id) REFERENCES buildout_reportfile(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**buildout_itemdescription:**

```
Indexes:
    "buildout_itemdescription_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "buildout_itemdescription_created_by_id_32dc4fc9" btree (created_by_id)
    "buildout_itemdescription_description_category_1_c_35f46dc6_idx" btree (description, category_1, category_2, category_3, manufacturer_sku, manufacturer_name, distributo
r_sku, supplier_id, unit_of_measure, quantity_in_unit_of_measure, region_id)
    "buildout_itemdescription_distributor_name_id_ae72fd8a" btree (supplier_id)
    "buildout_itemdescription_modified_by_id_58cf6676" btree (modified_by_id)
    "buildout_itemdescription_product_code_id_084c51de" btree (product_code_id)
    "buildout_itemdescription_region_id_c1682fff" btree (region_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "buildout_itemdescrip_modified_by_id_58cf6676_fk_auth_user" FOREIGN KEY (modified_by_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "buildout_itemdescrip_product_code_id_084c51de_fk_buildout_" FOREIGN KEY (product_code_id) REFERENCES buildout_itemref(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "buildout_itemdescrip_region_id_c1682fff_fk_buildout_" FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES buildout_region(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "buildout_itemdescrip_supplier_id_525b55c4_fk_buildout_" FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES buildout_supplier(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "buildout_itemdescription_created_by_id_32dc4fc9_fk_auth_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (created_by_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**Here are the relevant models:**

**LineItem**

```
class LineItem(BaseModel):
    '''
        Field summary: date, month, unit_price, extended_sell,
        list_price, list_price_ext, agreed_price, agreed_price_ext,
        baseline_price, baseline_price_ext, item_class,
        user_created_by, report_file, item_description
    '''
    # make a model regarding the file
    # and include filename = db.Column(db.String())
    # link to it as a foreign key

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects = LineItemManager()

    date = models.DateField(
        _("Date"),
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False,
        blank=False,
        null=True
    )
    month = models.DateField(
        _("Month"),
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False,
        blank=False,
        null=True
    )
    quantity = models.IntegerField(
        _("Qty"),
        null=True,
        blank=False,
    )

    unit_price = models.DecimalField(
        _("Unit Price"),
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=2
    )
    extended_sell = models.DecimalField(
        _("Ext Sell"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    list_price = models.DecimalField(
        _("List Price"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    list_price_ext = models.DecimalField(
        _("List Price Ext"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    agreed_price = models.DecimalField(
        _("Agreed Price"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    agreed_price_ext = models.DecimalField(
        _("Agreed Price Ext"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    baseline_price = models.DecimalField(
        _("Baseline Price"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    baseline_price_ext = models.DecimalField(
        _("Baseline Price Ext"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_digits=19,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    item_class = models.CharField(
        _("Class"),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    user_created_by = models.CharField(
        _("User Created By"),
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    report_file = models.ForeignKey(
        ReportFile,
        verbose_name="Report File",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    item_description = models.ForeignKey(
        "ItemDescription",
        verbose_name=_("Item Desc"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    sub_region = models.CharField(
        _("Sub Region"),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    business_unit = models.CharField(
        _("Sub Region"),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    # TODO: client property is untested
    @property
    def client(self):
        return self.report_file.report.client

    @property
    def date_with_fallback(self):
        if self.date:
            return self.date
        if self.month:
            return self.month
        return None

    @client.setter
    def client(self, value):
        self.report_file.report.client = value

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.date} {self.list_price}"
```

**ItemRef**

```
class ItemRef(BaseModel):
    identification_method = models.ForeignKey(
        'IdentificationMethod',
        verbose_name=_("Identification Method"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    identification_values = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**ItemDescription**

```
class ItemDescription(BaseModel):
    '''
        Field summary:
            description, category_1, category_2, category_3
            manufacturer_sku, manufacturer_name, distributor_sku,
            supplier, unit_of_measure,
            quantity_in_unit_of_measure, product_code, region
    '''
    description = models.TextField(
        _("desc"),
        blank=False,
        null=True
    )
    category_1 = models.CharField(
        _("Cat 1"),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    category_2 = models.CharField(
        _("Cat 2"),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    category_3 = models.CharField(
        _("Cat 3"),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    manufacturer_sku = models.CharField(
        _("Mfr SKU"),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
    )

    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(
        _("Mfr Name"),
        max_length=200,
        null=True,
    )
    distributor_sku = models.CharField(
        _("Dist SKU"),
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
    )

    unit_of_measure = models.CharField(
        _("UOM"),
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
    )

    quantity_in_unit_of_measure = models.IntegerField(
        _("Qty In UOM"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    product_code = models.ForeignKey(
        ItemRef,
        verbose_name=_("Product Code"),
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    supplier = models.ForeignKey(
        Supplier,
        verbose_name=_("Dist Name"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region, verbose_name=_("Region"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def get_fields(self, fields):
        # returns the selected fields as a list and the id
        result = []
        for field in fields:
            value = getattr(self, field)
            result.append(value)
        return tuple(result), self.pk

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.description)

    class Meta:
        index_together = [
            [
                'description', 'category_1', 'category_2',
                'category_3', 'manufacturer_sku', 'manufacturer_name',
                'distributor_sku', 'supplier', 'unit_of_measure',
                'quantity_in_unit_of_measure', 'region'
            ]
        ]
```

I've tried running `analyze` on the tables in Postgres, but it didn't help. In the question I linked to, the answer was to add an index but I'm not sure what index I'd add here.

Comment: Can you show us the django queries you used?

Comment: I added in a simplified version of my Django code

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: Just what Django and Postgres are creating by default. The item description table has an index of all of its fields together for a different query. I can paste in what info postgres has about the indexes.

Comment: An index for `unit_price` is conspicuously missing from `lineitem`; this is probably where I would start.

Comment: `lineitem`.`date` is another index candidate given your filter (although probably not related to the slowdown).

Comment: Thanks, I've added indexes for both of those. The longer query is now at 7.0 down from 7.3. Any bit helps but the main problem remains. Would a Django denormalization library help?

Comment: I found https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in which is interesting as that WHERE IN clause seems to be key for the slowdown but I'm not sure how to fix it with the ORM.

Comment: I'd be suprised if the `IN` clause is relevant, but you can exchange it for an equality comparison to a single value and run the query in the db shell to check.

Comment: With luck, querying `ItemDescription` instead of `LineItem` might give Postgres a clue. If you post the models, we can have a go at it.

Comment: I'll try querying ItemDescription instead. I added the models. I was thinking it was going to be more of a Postgres issue rather than a Django issue so I haven't had a chance to reduce irrelevant code as much as I'd like.

Comment: @EndreBoth I swapped the FROM and INNER JOIN but got the same exact timing so I guess it is equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190674/discussion-between-endre-both-and-zev).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PostgreSQL mistakenly thinks that it can be fast by scanning the rows in `product_code_id` order until it has found the first one satisfying all conditions, but it is not aware that the first matching row is not close to the beginning. So it ends up executing more of the nested loop join than it bargained for.

*Removing* that index would speed up the query, but if that is not an option, try using

```
...
ORDER BY buildout_itemdescription.product_code_id + 0
LIMIT 5
```

Then PostgreSQL cannot use the index.

Comment: Following your answer is still giving me the best performance but some db tuning for SSD has helped as well https://amplitude.engineering/how-a-single-postgresql-config-change-improved-slow-query-performance-by-50x-85593b8991b0

Comment: Sure. Telling your database about your hardware is a good idea. I would also increase `effective_io_concurrency`.

Comment: I have also found out that, if there are multiple joins in the statement and this is not enough to "guide" the planner, a solution is to move the most effective join into a separate CTE. This definitely forces the planner to use indices for the joins and in the strict order you present.

Comment: This has changed in PostgreSQL v12.

Comment: The best answer in the internet, i was trying out all other solutions which preferred by lots of people, i thought in this case index will make the query faster, but it was not, now I'm getting 346x better performance

Comment: Same problem at v16

Comment: @Strauteka Huh?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I got the same issue, as well with v16.1 and the suggested workaround still works